# Finding a node in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a question about a method that should find a node in a binary tree, that contains a given `value`. The method provided below doesn't work, and the question is why.

```
public Node search(Node node, int value) {
    if(node.value == value) return node;
    if(node.left != null) search(node.left, value);
    if(node.right != null) search(node.right, value);
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that this method sometimes returns `null` when there actually is a node with a given `value` in the tree. Why is that?

Comment: Insufficient code to tell.   Why is your binary tree not using generics?  It'd be more useful if you could store any reference type.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't ignore the value returned by the recursive call, and your method should not use `root`, but the passed `node` :

```
public Node search(Node node, int value) {
    if(node.value == value) return node;
    Node found = null;
    if(node.left != null)
        found = search(node.left, value);
    if(found == null && node.right != null)
        found = search(node.right, value);
    return found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Eran said, your calls to search via the `if` statements aren't returning a node, as your `search` function is supposed to. The only situation in which your current code would work is if the first node `n` satisfies `n.value == value`.